# Why my Tables get cleared when i use hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have used hibernate along with oracle to create some project... I had many mappings in it.. After mapping when i execute the program then it works Nicely but whn i  reexecute the program then my tables get cleared... any idea y?

Comment: Post your hibernate configuration please. Are you using hbm2ddl anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

somewhere in your config you have a property called `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` set to the value `create` or `create-drop`. Just delete that property or assign the value `do_nothing`.

If you set that property to an invalid value (such as `do_nothing`), hibernate doesn't do anything.

You can check the documentation of that property [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties).

Comment: my hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to "create" and some times its set to "update"... if i remove the property then will it affect my code?

Comment: Not your code, but the way hibernate behaves. Check the documentation.